# How to render JFreeChart to gsp using grails

Tags: jfreechart, grails-2.0

I am new to grails. I am not able to render the JFree Chart BAr graph to my gsp. rather it is being rendered as individual image. I want bboth my gsp forms and chart to be rendered on the same gsp. Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Can you please provide me some links for the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
def chart = ...

def buffer = chart.createBufferesImage( 700, 200 )
def bytes = EncoderUtil.encode( buffer, 'png' )

response.contentType = 'image/png'
response.contentLength = bytes.length
def out = response.outputStream
out.write( bytes )
out.flush()
out.close()
```

from Cartagena Colombia !!!

Comment: Can you please explain a bit?